# Convergence of cosine

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following sequence

$$(\cos (\pi \sqrt{ n^2 + n}))_{n=1}^\infty $$

converge?

I was trying the ratio or root test, but they don't seem to work in this case.

Mean value theorem?!

Comment: Expand $\sqrt{n^2+n} = \sqrt{n} + \dotsc$ to get an idea of the values.

Answer (score 1):

- $\sqrt{n^{2}+n}= n \cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \approx n\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$
- $\cos{(\pi\sqrt{n^{2}+n})} \approx \cos{\left(n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$

Comment: There is no $\;n\;$ multiplying $\;\pi\;$ inside the cosine's argument in the question...but I think you're right in your final expression:$$ \cos \left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)\cong \cos \left(n\pi\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\right)= \cos\left(n\pi+\frac\pi2\right) $$ Yet this last function is identically zero, not $\;(-1)^n\;$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the absolute value of the sequence, then $|\cos(x_n)| = |\cos(x_n -n \pi)|$, with $x_n = \pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}$. Then factor out the $\pi$ and use the identity $a-b = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a+b}$. You'll be able to take the limit then, and get the answer (it converges to zero).